# Сумма заказа с учётом дополнений продукта. WooCommerce Rest Api

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, rest

На сайте используются аддоны и дополнения к товарам. Они прекрасно работают и когда я получаю заказ, через WooCommerce Rest Api то вижу общую цену заказа с учётом выбранных дополнений к продуктам. Но если я пытаюсь добавить заказ через WooCommerce Rest Api, то даже правильно указав дополнения, они добавляются в заказ, заказ создаётся, но цена не меняется. Она остаётся такой, как если бы мы выбрали только товар, без дополнений.
Как я могу исправить это?

Пока что мысли только в сторону создание своей конечной точки добавления заказа, где буду регулировать цену

--обновлено--

Ощущение, что цена товара с учётом дополнений формируется в реальном времени, при выборе дополнений на сайте и "запекается" когда заказ сформирован. На скриншоте данные заказа, сделанные через сам сайт. Как можно видеть, в `meta_data(массив дополнений)` не указано никаких total или price. При этом price самого товара 765. Хотя реальная цена без дополнений 450. т.е. цена дополнений как бы "втыкается" в реальную стоимость, а не просто накладывается сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же я создам такой же заказ, с такими же дополнениями удалённо средствами WooCommerce REST API, дополнения так же будут отображаться в `meta_data` но price товара как был 450 так и останется.

Так же я пробовал сначала создать заказ, а затем обновить добавив аддоны в `meta_data`, но это не увенчалось успехом. Аддоны добавляются, но цена не обновляется.

Comment: Скорее всего неправильно работаешь с Rest Api при добавлении.

Comment: Да вроде правильно. Я указываю дополнения в ```meta_data```товара в виде объекта ```{key: 'ключ', value: 'значение'}``` REST в ответ присылает созданный заказ, где в метаданных подтягивается описание дополнения, заголовок и т.д. т.е. он находит дополнение. Я пробовал указывать цену в общем заказе, в продукте, в дополнениях, но это не помогло. REST сам определяет цену в зависимости от указанных товаров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: В line_items при сборке заказа, в каждом продукте можно указать total. Подвох в том, что он должен быть в виде строки `total: "250"` и тогда это будет работать.